# What is SponsorR?

Tags: torproject.org

When going through bugs and the Tor wiki, mailing lists, etc. I frequently see SponorR. What is meant by that?

An example: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15618

Comment: I believe that is the MEMEX project.

Comment: Given that all sponsors are referred to via pseudonyms/codenames in all publicly available documentation (i.e. the [Tor wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors), etc.), is it safe to publicise information about project names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tor Project assigns to each sponsor a pseudonym which is simply a letter in the alphabet. According to the [sponsors](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors) wikipage the letters [A](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors/SponsorA) to [U](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors/SponsorU) and [Z](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors/SponsorZ) are already assigned. Some of those sponsored projects ended while work is done at some other projects.

The work on the SponsorR project is tracked on its [project page](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors/SponsorR) and there is also a [discussion at tor-dev](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2014-October/007642.html) (and you'll probably find some more if you're searching the archives). Besides that you can also follow all [SponsorR tickets](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/query?keywords=~SponsorR) in the trac system. So basically all that is SponsorR.

Behind the pseudonym SponsorR is some organisation, company etc. Sometimes sponsors don't want to be assigned with their name. Thatswhy The Tor Project uses those pseudonyms and not the real name of the organisation, company etc.

Comment: Correct. Nearly all of Tor's sponsors are actually just fine being named. We've had one or two over the years who requested anonymity, not because they wanted to keep it secret that they were funding us, but because politically they didn't think it was wise for them to advertise that they cared about open-source security and privacy tools. And since we're anonymity researchers, it seemed clear that naming all but one or two, which we then call out as "anonymous", wasn't the best way to help them achieve their privacy goals. That's how all the sponsors ended up with letters.

Comment: That said, take a look at our sponsors page, and at our financial reports, and at the comments in the blog post discussing transparency and our financials. Because we publish our annual 990 forms (once they're ready -- there's a 3-6 month delay generally while the auditors approve eveything), the sponsor letters don't keep any of our major funders actually secret. Think of it like adding another layer of indirection, which keeps everybody happy enough.

Comment: URLs for above comment:
https://www.torproject.org/about/sponsors | 
https://www.torproject.org/about/financials |
https://blog.torproject.org/blog/transparency-openness-and-our-2013-financials

Answer (score 2):

As Richard commented, all sponsors are referred to via pseudonyms/codenames, like SponsorE, SponsorF, SponsorO etc. Each have their specific and non specific tasks/ topics that they work on. It's a little difficult listing all topics that SponserR covers. It was started last September i believe. Let me give you a link to their wiki, where it's explained clearly.

This is the list of the sponsors. --> https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors . You can find info about SponsorR from there itself.

(https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/sponsors/SponsorR/Terminology)

Hope this solves your question.